# module.exports not caching when using coffeescript to run my node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

Lets say that I have an application:

./app.coffee:

```
express = require "express"
module.exports = app = express()
require "./models"
```

./models/index.coffee

```
app = require "../app"
```

Then I run the command: `coffee app.coffee`

The problem is that the code does not run the same way as when it is precompiled.

When I run my app with `node` (compiled):

- The `app.coffee` requires `models`
- `models` requires `app` and returns the `module.exports` (app)

When I run my app with `coffee`:

- The `app.coffee` requires `models`
- `models` requires `app` but app run again and requires models again

It seems that module.exports is not working properly when running my app with `coffee`. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node has an altered behavior for managing [module cycles](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles) which doesn't appear to be supported when using the `coffee` executable:

> When there are circular `require()` calls, a module might not be done being executed when it is returned.
>
> [...]
>
> When `main.js` loads `a.js`, then `a.js` in turn loads `b.js`. At that point, `b.js` tries to load `a.js`. In order to prevent an infinite loop an **unfinished copy** of the `a.js` exports object is returned to the `b.js` module. `b.js` then finishes loading, and its exports object is provided to the `a.js` module.

If you can, try to avoid cycles. One possible alternative is:

```
express = require "express"
module.exports = app = express()
models = require "./models"
models app
```

```
module.exports = (app) ->
  # ...
```